# AWS S3 Bucket Policy for CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am trying to figure out how to follow [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks.html#access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks-error-data-type-mismatch) to set up an S3 bucket on AWS. I have been trying most of the year but still can't make sense of the AWS documentation. I think [this github repo readme](https://github.com/NoQuarterTeam/boilerplate/blob/main/docs/setup-s3.md) may have been prepared at a time when the AWS S3 interface appeared differently (there is no CORS setting in the form to make the S3 bucket permissions now).

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70749286/aws-s3-bucket-cors-configuration-policy-block-despite-all-access) earlier this year, and I have tried using the upvoted answer to make a bucket policy, which is precisely as shown in that answer, as:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

> Ln 1, Col 0Data Type Mismatch: The text does not match the expected
> JSON data type Object. Learn more

The Learn More link goes to a page that suggests I can resolve this error by updating text to use the supported data type. I do not know what that means in this context. I don't know how to find out which condition keys require which type of data.

> Resolving the error
>
> Update the text to use the supported data type.
>
> For example, the Version global condition key requires a String data
> type. If you provide a date or an integer, the data type won't match.

Can anyone help with current instructions for how to create the CORS permissions that are consistent with the spirit of the instructions in the github readme for the repo?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a bucket in the aws console, IE search S3, click on Create Bucket, give the bucket a name, likely uncheck block all public access, and hit create.
2. Click on your bucket in the console, click on permissions tab, scroll down to bucket policy, edit the policy and paste in your very code (I just used it on a bucket of mine ;')

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

3. Save the bucket

This should now be publicly accessible and accept any origin with CORS.