# Amazon S3 CORS Error but configuration set

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I'm new to S3 and setting up an S3 Bucket to store and display images. This works fine when loading in a browser but when trying to download some of these assets using Javascript I get the standard CORS error (urls redacted):

```
Access to fetch at 's3_url' from origin 'site_url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I've updated my CORS configuration in S3 to the below but it doesn't seem to resolve it:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried with and without exposing the header and I've tried adding HEAD to the allowed methods as mentioned here: [AWS S3 Bucket CORS configuration: policy block despite all access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70749286/aws-s3-bucket-cors-configuration-policy-block-despite-all-access)

I need this to be accessible from localhost for local development so I cannot restrict to just my live domain.

Am I missing a step here?